# Double Border Line Not Displayed

Tags: birt

I am trying to use Double border line to underline the amount field. 
I simply selected "**Double**" from **Properties->Border->Style** but on viewer and also on PDF output, it is just a thick line not a double.
Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: it works for me both in viewer and pdf. Most likely you defined the border twice (for example on cell bottom and row bottom), overriding the double-line property.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes, it suspected that at first but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved! 
It seems the line width has to be more. than 3 px and I just didn't know that